# A sentence (or a group of sentences) s.t. every letter of the alphabet is included exactly once

Tags: выражения

I recently came to an interesting concept called **pangram**. Pangram is a sentence that uses each letter of the alphabet at least once. A famous example is "Съешь же ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.", which is also used in Windows' fontview.exe.

What I'm seeking for is a specific type of pangram where each letter of the alphabet is included **exactly once**. Kinda like japanese poem [Iroha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iroha), but with the restriction to russian language. I made a small web application that lets one verify [whether a sentence is a pangram](https://bumbread.github.io/pangram).

Since there are more consonants than vowels and each syllable has to contain exactly one vowel, one has to make sure that each syllable contained as much consonant letters as possible. With the help of some sources I found a few very long syllables such as "ктябрь" and "взбзднуть".

Here I have a prototype of a phrase that has every letter exactly once and makes the whole thing as a pronouncible syllables

"сбзднуть крашиц жлой щя вэп гемф чъю хы"

This shows that it is kind of possible, but unfortunately the sentence above hardly is composed of all-russian-words nor does it make any sense. Is there an example of a sentence that has each letter of the alphabet exactly once?

Comment: what is mean "all-russian-words" here ? The above phrase "..крашиц.."-etc doesn't consist of words, but represents some kind of indigestible gibberish, sorry

Comment: this is easily googleable - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0 (see "панграммы на русском языке)

Comment: @Пилум I said that it's not composed of russian words. That's what the sentence says.

Comment: bumbread, ok, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fairly wide range of Russian pangrams can be found in the corresponding [Wikipedia article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5).
My translation of a fragment of this article:

Without «ъ» or «ё» (used to check telegraphic communication that not use these letters):

```
В чащах юга жил бы цитрус? Да, но фальшивый экземпляр!
Друг мой эльф! Яшке б свёз птиц южных чащ!
```

Each letter once:

```
Любя, съешь щипцы, — вздохнёт мэр, — кайф жгуч.
Шеф взъярён тчк щипцы с эхом гудбай Жюль.
Эй, жлоб! Где туз? Прячь юных съёмщиц в шкаф.
Экс-граф? Плюш изъят. Бьём чуждый цен хвощ!
Эх, чужак! Общий съём цен шляп (юфть) — вдрызг!
Эх, чужд кайф, сплющь объём вши, грызя цент.
Чушь: гид вёз кэб цапф, юный жмот съел хрящ.
```

Used in operating systems:

- Microsoft uses in fontview.exe for Cyrillic fonts pangram without the particle «же»:
  `Съешь [же] ещё этих мягких французских булок да выпей чаю.`
- KDE uses a pangram:
  `Широкая электрификация южных губерний даст мощный толчок подъёму сельского хозяйства.`
- GNOME uses a pangram:
  `В чащах юга жил бы цитрус? Да, но фальшивый экземпляр!`